# Should I use chunks() or save() to save files in Django?

Tags: python, django, file

I'm a little confused. When saving an uploaded file in Django should I save it using FileSystemStorage( fs.save() ) or should I use chunks? I just want to ensure that I use chunking to save files that are large so that they don't impact performance. But I'm also reading [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/189mhur/chunks_or_save/) that files over 2.5MB are streamed to memory by default so does that make chunking obsolete?